# Math.cos - Cant get right answer

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I am trying to convert the result of cosA which is 0.25 to Degrees. The answer should be 75.5... but I am getting 0.9... Can someone help me please ?

Here is my code

```
var b = 6;
var a = 8;
var c = 7;


var cosA = ((b*b)+(c*c)-(a*a))/(2*b*c);
console.log(cosA);
cosA = Math.cos(cosA);
console.log(cosA);
```

Comment: hint: radians are not degrees

Comment: cosines range from +1 to -1 .... cos(x) resulting in 75.5 is not possible

Comment: you need  inverse cosine transform..as cosine ranges between -1 and +1

Comment: AkshaJ, How do I inverse the cosine transform?

Answer (score 4):

wht you need is

```
Math.acos(0.25) * 180/Math.PI
```

the `* 180 / Math.PI` converts radians to degrees

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.acos(0.25) * 180/Math.PI
```

This will return you inverse cosine transform and we multiple it by the 180/pi to convert radian to degrees :)